# My Nullable DateTime view is failing with a Null

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, datetime

In my MVC app, I have a shared `DateTime.cshtml` view defined like this:

```
@model DateTime?
@{
    var value = "";
    if (Model.HasValue) 
    {
        value = String.Format("{0:d}", Model.Value);
    }
}
@Html.TextBox("", value, new { @class = "form-control datepicker", type = "text" })
```

In one of my views I use it like this:

```
@model PublicationSystem.ViewModels.ProfileEdit
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.BirthDate, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.BirthDate)
    </div>
</div>
```

However, if my model has a `Null` for BirthDate, I get this message:

> The model item passed into the dictionary is null, but this dictionary requires a non-null model item of type 'System.DateTime'.

In the model `ProfileEdit` I have the field defined like this:

```
[DataType(DataType.Date), Display(Name = "Birth Date")]
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
public DateTime? BirthDate { get; set; }
```

How can I get it to load the view, even if there is a Null there? What am I doing wrong?

PS, I've read other posts, similar to this, most of which say make my Model for the Editor control nullable, but as you can see, I do that already.

*Update:*

Here is the controller action (Mapper.Map simply takes the Model, and populates the ViewModel `ProfileEdit`):

```
[CheckId(RedirectToReferrer = true)]
public virtual ActionResult Edit(Guid id)
{
    var profileEdit = Mapper.Map<ProfileEdit>(db.Profile.Find(id));

    if (profileEdit == null)
    {
        return HttpNotFound();
    }

    return View(profileEdit);
}
```

Comment: "The model item passed into the dictionary is null, but this dictionary requires a non-null model item of type 'System.DateTime'." Where is the dictionary declared and how is it declared?

Comment: I don't know. Perhaps MVC is using something else to render the editor.

Comment: I tested your template and it work without any error. Show us your control action the one that send the view

Comment: Have you tried removing those attributes on your BirthDate property, and seeing if you view renders without error?

Comment: Yes, tried that too. Still the same error. It's like it's using the wrong Editor template. Not sure to check to see which one it is using.

Comment: The template can be simply `@model DateTime? @Html.TextBox("", "{0:d}", new { @class = "form-control datepicker" })` (the rest is not necessary). If your getting that error, its because you are calling another view/template, not the one you have shown

Comment: @StephenMuecke I thought so, but how do I know what template it is pulling? Why wouldn't it use my template?

Comment: Is that template in the `/Views/Shared/EditorTemplates` folder?

Comment: Yes. There was a file excluded that was an old Date template. When I removed it from the EditorTemplates folder, the view started to work, but not using my template.

Answer (score 0):

@Mangist was right. It was this attribute:

```
[DataType(DataType.Date), Display(Name = "Birth Date")]
```

Specifically, the DataType, since it was `Date` not `DateTime` like my template was for.